# MS Access (JET) にて、複数テーブルを括弧なしで結合する記法

Tags: sql, ms-access

Access にて複数テーブルを結合する場合は、JOIN ON ごとに括弧で括るのが普通だと思います。
つまり、

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID=C.ID;
```

は Access ではエラーとなるので、以下の書き方を通常はすると思います。

```
SELECT * FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID) LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID=C.ID;
```

しかし、昔の担当者が書いたコードで以下のものを見つけ、動作したので驚きました。

```
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID, LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID=C.ID;
```

Web で日本語サイトと英語サイトを探してみたのですが、この書き方についての情報を見つけることができませんでした。もし、この書き方をご存知の方がおられましたら、情報をいただきたいのですが……　
よろしくお願いいたします。